# How to get the text of this Element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can I get ***Item - mar3 has been awarded to another traveler.*** text from the `html` provided below?

My Script.

```
package garbage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class mailinator {
 static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.mailinator.com/inbox.jsp?to=679jcscqgtm1guuq09aef3mofu");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[normalize-space(text())='Item awarded']")).click();
        // driver.switchTo().frame("rendermail");
           System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/p[3]")).getText().trim());


        }
}
```

And, the `HTML`

```
<p>
Item - 
<b>mar3</b>
 has been awarded to another traveler.
</p>
```

And, also the image [here](http://postimg.org/image/ar334aqkd/)

Comment: Please provide `html` along with the code you have tried with.

Comment: Please avoid providing image links and post the relevant HTML as a text into the question.

Comment: @SusheelThakur This is very LEAST amount of `html` to write any kind of `xpath` selector for this scenario.

Comment: @Saifur Thanks
Please go to this URL
http://www.mailinator.com/inbox.jsp?to=679jcscqgtm1guuq09aef3mofu
CLick on first Mail Item awarded  you will get that screen
Hope this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your post. My understanding is you want *Item awarded* text only. If so 
Try

```
//ul[@id="mailcontainer"]/li[1]/a/div[2]
```

I also think, as per your comment, the content is inside an `iframe`. So all you have to use

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name='rendermail']")));

String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p:nth-child(3)")).getText();

System.out.println(text);
```

Just tested. The code above works perfectly.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Saifur,
once you click Item Awarded you will see a page where it is written
**Item - mar3 has been awarded to another traveler.**.

Comment: Not working got this exception
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"p:nth-child(3)"}

and its not in frame i commented it in the code

Comment: @SusheelThakur try `By css = By.cssSelector(".container table p:nth-child(3)");

WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(css));
String text = myDynamicElement.getText();
System.out.println(text);`